# Flash effect with Adobe Premiere

Tags: premiere

How can we simulate a camera flash with Premiere Pro? I know the stroboscope effect but it's not very realistic.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a single white frame and/or crank the brightness up very high for one frame.  A photo flash  is very fast (much, much less than a single frame) so the impact in video would only be for one frame of video.